# Sending a message from FCM Console not working for Web Tokens

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am implementing Web Push Notification in an application and I have successfully registered the client app with GCM. I have the `subscription` object that contains the `endpoint` that looks like this.

`"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/dV4lSfI5J6Q:APA91bEU28F9YG5qNr3xSjvYlH2Mh1GPgiqMaRcjandHbpfqnVyAeZxqoE31OXYq4yzW2_vrkn74YHdgsITZP_6SELO8-xHf1hylquJefJdY85-Xx9AWTAPP9H6kfq7CKp23dsoQHbH`

I read and found out that we need to use a third party library like [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push) to send push using this `endpoint` to the clients because the payload needs to be encrypted according to spec. My objective is to send notifications to all my users, web + mobile, at once, using Firebase Console's Notification feature.

Is there a way to send push to web clients using Firebase console or to convert the GCM endpoint to an FCM token?

Update: If I try to use Firebase console to send push the token generated above, I get the following error.

[image: Error in Firebase Console]

Comment: The endpoint you keep on mentioning actually contains a registration token. It's the value `dV4lSfI5J6Q:APA91bEU28F9YG5qNr3xSjvYlH2Mh1GPgiqMaRcjandHbpfqnVyAeZxqoE31OXYq4yzW2_vrkn74YHdgsITZP_6SELO8-xHf1hylquJefJdY85-Xx9AWTAPP9H6kfq7CKp23dsoQHbH`

Comment: Yes, but can we use this token in Firebase console to send notifications? Because I tried, and I couldn't.

Comment: Was it returning any error when you tried? If it does, I suggest adding it in the post. It's also worth a shot trying to send a message using the FCM API instead of the console. See if returns a different result.

Comment: Making a POST to the FCM API works if I use this token. I added the error screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per testing this out, for some reason, registration tokens for Web are not *working* or allowed in the Firebase Console. Only tokens for Android and iOS do:

[image]

The request could still *proceed* where the console would show that it is *sent/complete*, but there wouldn't be any messages received.

Comment: Yes. I am hoping that if web app registers to FCM, using Firebase SDK, that token might work in the console. But I haven't tested it.